# Navigate to tkinter OptionMenu with tab key

Tags: python, tkinter

Lets say there is a tkinter window with an `Entry` field, an `OptionMenu` field and another `Entry` field. When pressing `Tab` on the first Entry of the window the focus is going to the next `Entry` instead of the `OptionMenu`. How can I solve this?

Minimal code to reproduce:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

# setting the windows size

root.geometry("600x400")

options = ['1', '2', '2']

entry1_var = tk.StringVar()
entry1_label = tk.Label(root, text='Entry 1', font=('calibre', 10, 'bold'))
entry1_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
entry1_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry1_var, font=('calibre', 10, 'normal'))
entry1_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

optionmenu1_var = tk.StringVar()
optionmenu1_label = tk.Label(root, text='OptionMenu 1', font=('calibre', 10, 'bold'))
optionmenu1_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
optionmenu1_entry = tk.OptionMenu(root, optionmenu1_var, *options )
optionmenu1_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

entry2_var = tk.StringVar()
entry2_label = tk.Label(root, text='Entry 2', font=('calibre', 10, 'bold'))
entry2_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
entry2_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry2_var, font=('calibre', 10, 'normal'))
entry2_entry.grid(row=6, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following configuration on the `OptionMenu` field solves the problem

```
optionmenu1_entry.config(takefocus=1)
```